# Java how to automate the retrieving of new values

Tags: java

I've been wondering if there's any predefined class in java to handle a permanent monitoring/listening to changes on a system, in my case this system is a MQ channel, I've already writed the relevant code that provide the current status of the related channel and store it in an oracle DB.., However i have to execute it each time in order to hand over a new value to the DB ..

can you please advise me ? any bright ideas regarding this.

Comment: Are you talking about a value which can be watched, so that methods will be called when it changes?

Comment: For a real program, I'd generally use Spring's `@MessageListener`.

Comment: YES @jartapsell, its a value that can be retrieved from the MQ channel directly  ( i have already the code to realise that ) ... actually method has to be called permanently whatevet the value.

Comment: Ok @chrylis, actually it's a very real program .. it seem a good idea to use this classe ,however iam not too strong in java. So can you maybe give more details about how to implement this code or how it will work after .

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to create a monitor class which will run a thread continuously and monitoring on the MQ. I have written codes for your where in comment section you have to put your code to handle your requirement. Hope this will help you:-

```
    public final class MonitorMQ {
    boolean keepProcessing_ = true;
    public MonitorMQ() {

            try {
                Thread t = new Thread(new HealthCheck());
                t.start();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }   
        }                   

    private class HealthCheck implements Runnable  {

        public HealthCheck() {  
        }       

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void run() {             
            do {
                //your MQ check codes 
                try {
                        System.out.println("I will add my health check code here");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }while (keepProcessing_);            
        }
    }

    private final synchronized void stopProcessing() {      
        keepProcessing_ = false;
    }

    public void destroy() {
        stopProcessing();       
    } 
}
```

Comment: THanks a lot @pritam .. i will try your code and provide feedback

Comment: No  problem wish you all the very best.